# Can Microdata be applied on any type of HTML element?

Tags: html, markup, microdata

In all examples around the web I see Microdata properties `itemscope` and `itemtype` being applied to `div` elements, like so:

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

But can Microdata be applied on any other element, in my case I want to apply it to a list item:

```
<ul>
<li itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Are there any known problems with this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I think this question **should be reopened**. It had a very small SEO side question, but I edited it out. However, the main question never was about SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, "Yes".  Check out the Google page yourself to see them use it in different tags: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176035?hl=en

Answer (score 8):

### You can use *every* HTML5 element for Microdata …

Microdata defines 5 new attributes for HTML5:

- `itemid`
- `itemprop`
- `itemref`
- `itemscope`
- `itemtype`

Let’s see where they can be used. [Section 5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#items) says:

> Every HTML element may have an `itemscope` attribute specified.

So *every* element can have `itemscope`. Further on it says:

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute may have an `itemtype` attribute specified

So if it has `itemscope` (and we learned that every element can have it), it can have `itemtype`, too. Next:

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute and an `itemtype` attribute […] may also have an `itemid` attribute specified

If it has `itemscope` and `itemtype`, it can have `itemid`, too. And:

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute may have an `itemref` attribute specified

If it has `itemscope`, it can have `itemref`.

Only `itemprop` is missing now. It’s defined in [Section 5.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute):

> Every HTML element may have an `itemprop` attribute specified

So `itemprop` can also be used on every element.

(Note that Microdata (W3C Note) [refers to the HTML5 spec for defining what a "HTML element" is](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#terminology), so essentially "HTML element" means "HTML5 element".)

### … but some elements get a different content model (when `itemprop` is used)

See [8.1 Content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#content-models).

For example:

- `href` becomes a required attribute for `a` and `area`
- `data` becomes a required attribute for `iframe`
- the attributes `name`, `http-equiv` and `charset` are no longer allowed on `meta`

### … and some elements have special rules for determining the property value (when `itemprop` is used)

See [5.4 Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values).

For example:

[Special rules for links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283706/1591669). Here `foobar`’s value is the URL `http://example.com/`, not the string `Link`:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" itemprop="foobar">Link</a>
```

Here `foobar`’s value is `5`, not `10`:

```
<data value="5" itemprop="foobar">10</data>
```

### And search engines should know this.

If Google or other search engine services support it can’t be answered definitely, as nothing can be answered with certainty when it comes to third party services that keep their code hidden. Even if they (seem to) support it today, we can’t know what will happen tomorrow. So such questions are usually not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

However, there is no reason to assume that search engines wouldn’t support it.

Comment: (Used this answer also on [my answer to question on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/63189/17633).)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jeremy Miller's answer:

Microdata essentially forms objects. In valid HTML, an element with the `itemscope` attribute contains all of the microdata associated with it. Also, the scope of each element with an `itemprop` is enough to contain all data necessary for that property.

Imagine replacing each `itemscope` element with the item itself; and replacing each `itemprop` element with the property itself, and its value. (Think XML)

In your example, the item would look like this:

```
<movie>
    <name>Avatar</name>
    <director>James Cameron</director>
    <genre>Science fiction</genre>
    <trailer>Trailer</trailer>
</movie>
```

This structure of `itemscope`s and `itemprop`s  can be applied to any suitable hierarchy of HTML elements, regardless of what elements they are. The long-winded answer is still yes, but I hope this has helped you understand how microdata is interpreted.

Also, I'm guessing your example is from [here](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html), but I suggest you give at least items 1a-1d a quick read.