# Listing job offers (schema.org’s JobPosting)

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have a page with list of jobs [jobs offers](http://www.presbium.sk/praca) and every job in list is link to page with job offer.

And I have a problem with Microdata, and my question is, which variant is better?

First variant:

```
<table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">  
  <tr>  
    <td itemprop="title" itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" itemscope>job 1</td>    
  </tr>  
  <tr>  
    <td itemprop="title" itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" itemscope>job 2</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>  
    <td itemprop="title" itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" itemscope>job 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Second variant:

```
<table>  
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">  
     <td itemprop="title"><a href..>job 1</a></td>  
  </tr>  
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">  
     <td itemprop="title"><a href..>job 2</a></td>  
  </tr>  
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">  
     <td itemprop="title"><a href..>job 3</a></td>  
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first variant means: There is a JobPosting which has three titles. Each of these titles consists of another JobPosting.

Your second variant means: There are three JobPostings, each one has a title.

So you want to go with your second variant.

Note that you have an error on your current page. Instead of the example contained in your question, on your page you use `itemprop="title"` on the `a` element. But then [the `href` value is the title, not the anchor text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669).

So instead of

```html
<td>
 <a itemprop="title" href="…" title="…">…</a>
</td>
<!-- the value of 'href' is the JobPosting title -->
```

you should use

```html
<td itemprop="title">
 <a class="list1" href="…" title="…">…</a>
</td>
<!-- the value of 'a' is the JobPosting title -->
```

And why not use the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) here?

```html
<td itemprop="title">
 <a itemprop="url" href="…" title="…">…</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one. The first one is describing a `table` as `JobPosting` which isn't a `JobPosting`.