# Is it possible to use microdata in a Tumblr blog?

Tags: tumblr, microdata, schema.org

I want to use schema.org in a tumblr blog. Can you use microdata in a Tumblr blog?

Comment: Did you try (apart from asking this question) ?

Comment: I did not yet try, but asked 2 different persons to do it for me, and one said it was not possible because it is Tumblr and the other said it is no problem, that is why I ask here now.

Comment: I down voted for the lack of effort. Please try, if you get stuck show your code. If one man said we couldn't fly and no one else tried, we wouldn't have gotten very far.

Comment: okay, that is cool! I will try and let you know what happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Microdata is an extension of HTML5. It’s ["just" five new attributes and "some" rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669).
2. Tumblr allows editing your theme’s HTML.
3. Tumblr allows adding HTML to your posts.

So yes, you can use Microdata in a Tumblr blog.

(Note that you may also use other syntaxes than Microdata. Schema.org is a vocabulary and [works also with RDFa Lite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633), for example.)