# Microdata on list markup not validating with W3C validator

Tags: html, microdata

I am brand new to Microdata and I am slowly getting it. But for some reason this does not validate with the W3C validator since I’m putting a `<div>` in the middle of a `<ul>`:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BeautySalon">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <b>
        <span itemprop="name">foobar and you</span>
      </b>
    </li>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <li>
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">6969 foobar</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Miami Beach</span>, 
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">FL</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">33139</span>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li>
      <span itemprop="telephone">305 691 6969</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How would I correctly add the

```
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
```

and correctly add all the `itemprop` and still be W3C valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` doesn’t allow `div` as child, so you can’t use it as container for several `li` elements. There are various possible solutions.

I think using `ul` here is not appropriate. But if you want to keep using `ul`:

It doesn’t seem to make sense that the street address is not in the same list item as the locality/region/postal code. So you might want to put them all in the same list item (and you might also want to use `br` for postal addresses).

If you want to use `b` for the name, you could omit the `span`. Either specify the Microdata on the `b` or (for consistency) on the `li`.

If you don’t need a separate element for the telephone number, you could specify the Microdata on the `li`.

This would give you:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BeautySalon">
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="name"><b>foobar and you</b></li>
    <li itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">6969 foobar</span><br>
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Miami Beach</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">FL</span><br>
      <span itemprop="postalCode">33139</span>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="telephone">305 691 6969</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You [can use every HTML5 element for Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669). Re-use your existing markup. Only if you need additional elements for Microdata, add and use `div`/`span` (and possibly [`meta`/`link`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)).