# What page type fits to schema.org type product?

Tags: product, schema.org, microdata

Regarding to schema.org there is a [QAPage](http://schema.org/QAPage) type that fits for [questions](http://schema.org/Question) and [answers](http://schema.org/Answer). But I can not find anything like `ProductPage`.

I assume another type of [webpage](http://schema.org/WebPage) should fit - but which one?

- <s>AboutPage</s>
- <s>CheckoutPage</s>
- <s>CollectionPage</s>
- <s>ContactPage</s>
- [ItemPage](http://schema.org/ItemPage)
- <s>MedicalWebPage</s>
- [ProfilePage](http://schema.org/ProfilePage)
- <s>QAPage</s>
- <s>SearchResultsPage</s>

I only see those two types that might fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest match would be [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) (emphasis mine):

> A page **devoted to a single item**, such as **a particular product** or hotel.

Note that Schema.org is currently missing a property to link to the "main item" this page is about, i.e., a [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) in your case. The [`mainContentOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) is [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23031666/1591669) for [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement). Some use the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about) for this purpose, but this usage is questionable.

Comment: Interesting - so I will use this as long as Schema.org has no better solution.

Comment: @Jurik: May I ask why you want to use a WebPage type in the first place? Wouldn’t it be sufficient to mark up the actual product with `Product`?

Comment: Yes, I will mark up the product as Product. But there is a difference between a `ProductPage` and a Page with several `Product`. I want use microdata to tell crawler that this is THE ProductPage and not a page with one (or more) Products. I think a `ProductPage` should be unique.

Comment: @Jurik: I see, but note that such a unique restriction is not imposed (and probably never will be). Usually, this is accomplished by using the [`url`](http://schema.org/url)/[`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs) properties (products on a category page will have their dedicated URL as value of the `url` property)