# Can you use plain text for addresses in schema.org markup?

Tags: html, schema.org, structured-data

I have a CMS that has a single text field for an [Organization](http://schema.org/Organization) address. The data is stored very inconsistently and, in many cases, I'm dealing with city/state only. I'm fairly new to schema.org and would like to know if I can simply do something like the following to handle the markup:

```
<p itemprop="address">Some city, WY</p>
```

As I said, I'm new to all this, but I guess I'm using the "Microdata" format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you may use text as value for [`address`](http://schema.org/address). While its expected value is another item (namely [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress)) instead of text, Schema.org [does not *require* this](http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html) (bold emphasis mine):

> While we would like all the markup we get to follow the schema, in practice, we expect a lot of data that does not. We expect schema.org properties to be used with new types. **We also expect that often, where we expect a property value of type Person, Place, Organization or some other subClassOf Thing, we will get a text string.** In the spirit of "some data is better than none", we will accept this markup and do the best we can.

However, it’s questionable if it’s really the "physical address" of an `Organization` if you only specify city and state.

If you would use a `PostalAddress` item as value, you could specify exactly what the address parts are that you provide, so consumers have a better chance to understand your data:

```
<p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
  <span itemprop="addressLocality">Some city</span>, 
  <span itemprop="addressRegion">WY</span>
</p>
```

(Terminology: You are using the *syntax*, or format, Microdata and the *vocabulary* Schema.org.)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you for the clarification. I would love to have a better data structure than just the text string, but the data has been put in over time and is inconsistently formatted to begin with. I could spend a lot of time trying to parse out the relevant parts in every scenario, but that's really not my aim with this. I'm simply trying to improve the SEO value of an existing set of pages using data that's already present. Sometimes I have street, sometimes city, sometimes state, sometimes all three. This simple designation of address as text is my only (feasible) option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that wouldn't really work, as the expected value for the "address" property is the PostalAddress type.  But you can simply do something like this as one possible option:

```
<span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/City">
<span itemprop="name">City Name</span>, State
</span>
```

I wouldn't recommend that you use the PostalAddress type because technically the postal address should be the full mailing address.

David