# "Blog is not a known valid target type for the mainContentOfPage"

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, microdata

> Blog is not a known valid target type for the mainContentOfPage property.

I have tried many optins to set `mainContentOfPage` property on http://www.thecreativedev.com

I have

```
<div itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"> --> This is outside the loop

<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost"> --> This is in loop
```

But no solution worked. I tried solution provided on [Best way to markup "mainContentOfPage"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023263/best-way-to-markup-maincontentofpage)

Anyone can help me in this?

Comment: Do you have a `WebPage` (or similar) item around the `div` with the `mainContentOfPage` property? -- Is this example snippet from the blog’s homepage? And for a page about a single blog post you use different markup?

Comment: This is the snippet set on blog homepage.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you don’t want to use the [`mainContentOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage). It’s not really useful for the average webpage, because it expects a [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) as value (which represents things like the navigation, the footer or the sidebar), not what is *actually* the main content of a page (like a blog post).

If you want to denote that the [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) is the primary thing the [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) is about (e.g., on the blog’s homepage), you might want to use the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity) (and for the other direction, the inverse property [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage)).

It could look like this (using Microdata):

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <section itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
    <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
    <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
    <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: you mean maincontentofPage is not required as this is blog site? and can replace mainentitypage?

Comment: @BhumiShah: Schema.org never requires that certain properties have to be used, but you might have of course other parties that "require" something like that. Anyway, to decide if you can simply replace the property, you would have to include a minimal (!) example of your markup in your question.

Comment: unor: I am not getting you.I don't have much knowledge about rich content  so,

Comment: What I mean is, if you want a more specific answer, you should edit your question to include a short markup example (= show us the relevant parts of your Microdata with how you use `mainContentOfPage` currently).

Comment: You can check my domain url on google tool. They are showing error.

Comment: @BhumiShah: I know, but it’s important that you include a minimal example in your question -- otherwise, if you change something on your live page (or if you delete your site, etc.), this question is not useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your suggestion. Will  improve question

Comment: unor: You are awesome.Thanks.